# What does $C^{\text{1,stw}}(0,b)$ mean

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, notation

I know that this C with the one means continoulsy differentiable functions but what does this stw stand for? Does anyone know this?

Comment: Where did you find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reminds me of the abbreviation for the german word "stückweise" - in this case, $C^{1,\text{stw}}$ denotes the set of piecewise continuously differentiable functions. But depending on the context, it could mean something totally different.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you!

Comment: @Lipschitz You are welcome. By the way, you can mark answers as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.